# wpf how to get mouse position in container when dragging controls inside?

Tags: wpf

I want to get mouse position of container while dragging controls inside so I can add auto-scroll logic to container. However, MouseMove does not fired at all when dragging, DragOver fired only when dragging over controls inside.

**test example**

Draggable gizmo:

```
public class Gizmo : TextBlock
    {
        public Gizmo()
        {
            this.AllowDrop = true;
            this.Background = Brushes.Gray;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(6);
        }

        public Gizmo(string content) : this()
        {
            this.Text = content;
        }

        private bool isDragging;
        private Point lastPressedLocation;

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (!this.isDragging)
                {
                    Point newLocation = e.GetPosition(this);
                    Vector offset = this.lastPressedLocation - newLocation;
                    if (offset.LengthSquared > 36)
                    {
                        this.lastPressedLocation = newLocation;
                        this.isDragging = true;

                        System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, DateTime.Now, DragDropEffects.Move);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.isDragging = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool canDrop;

        protected override void OnPreviewDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("drag enter inside");
            if (this.Text == "gizmo 1")
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                this.canDrop = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
                this.canDrop = false;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            base.OnPreviewDragEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("drag over inside");
            if (this.canDrop)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            base.OnPreviewDragOver(e);
        }
    }
```

container:

```
public class Container : WrapPanel
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
                this.Children.Add(new Gizmo(string.Format("gizmo {0}", i)));

            base.OnInitialized(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDragEnter(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("drag enter outside");
            base.OnPreviewDragEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDragOver(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            //I want to get mouse postion here, but this will be called only when dragging over gizmo inside
            Console.WriteLine("drag over outside");
            base.OnPreviewDragOver(e);
        }
    }
```

[running result and question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jVdm.png)

or it's just impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last function in your code should work. Alternatively (since there should be no other elements handling the event before you) you can use the `OnDragOver` method instead of the `Preview`.

```
protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
}
```

If it doesn't work, that usually means that specific area of your control is not hit-test visible. Make sure `IsHitTestVisible` is `true` (has to be, otherwise child elements wouldn't work either) and that the `Background` of your control is not `null`. If you want no background and still be able to be hit-test visible, use `Transparent` for the background.